# AFrame spherical environment maps appear to be constrained to the camera

Tags: three.js, aframe

The spherical environment maps in A-Frame appear to be tied to the rotation of the camera. The reflections in static objects change when the camera is rotated (no translation). This problem seems connected directly to the rotation of the camera. 
Here's an example with static objects including a plane below the camera. Rotating the camera results in incorrect reflections in the objects.

https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/smsinger-test/aframe/tests/sph_env_map/index.html

The map also appears to be pinching at the poles - does the sphericalEnvMap not take an equi-rectangular image?